# How to grab return value from an ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I wanted to grab the value on an ajax call using a function. but the value always return as undefined. return value is only 1 or 0.

Here is my code:

```
$(function(){ 
   $('#add_product').click(function(){ 
     var i = $('#product_name').val(); 
     param = 'product_name='+i; 
     var value = check_product(param); 
     alert(value); 
     return false; 
   }); 
});

function check_product(param){ 
  $.ajax({ 
    type : 'POST', 
    data : param, 
    url : baseurl+'cart/check_product_name/', 
    success : function(result){ 
      //alert(result); 
      return result; 
    } 
 });
}
```

---

I am still working on getting this one work. I get the value now showing 1 or 0. What im trying to accomplish now is how I can it in the if statement. I wanted to have something like this. If val = 0 return true; else return false. Im not sure I'm in the right track of using the ajax function. But if there a better way you can show me I will appreciate it.

```
$(function(){ 
       $('#add_product').click(function(){ 
         var i = $('#product_name').val(); 
         param = 'product_name='+i; 
         check_product(param).done(function(value) {
        var val = value; //waits until ajax is completed
         });
         if(val == 0){
            return true;
         } else{
            return false;
         }
       }); 
    });

function check_product(param){ 
  return $.ajax({ 
    type : 'POST', 
    data : param, 
    url : baseurl+'cart/check_product_name/'
 });
}
```

Comment: the 'a' in 'ajax' stands for asynchronous...:) so you need to do the actions that depend on the result in your success handler

Comment: Could you provide the PHP/script too? also have you checked that you PHP/script is actually getting the variables that you are passing?

Comment: There's also `async: false` for the request. I wouldn't use that though :p

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's asynchronous, so you have to wait for the ajax call to get the data back before you can alert it. You can do that easily by returning the ajax call and using `done()`, like so:

```
$(function() {
    $('#add_product').click(function() {
        var i   = $('#product_name').val(),
            par = 'product_name=' + i;

        check_product(par).done(function(value) {
            alert(value); //waits until ajax is completed
        });

        return false;
    });
});

function check_product(param) {
    return $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        data : param,
        url  : baseurl + 'cart/check_product_name/'
    });
}​
```

Comment: Never thought of returning a deffered object, +1. Normally, I'd just pass a callback.

Comment: @JanDvorak - Thanks, used to always use callbacks myself, but just returning the deferred object exposes done, fail and always directly and makes it a lot easier in my opinion.

Comment: +1, I've been looking for a way to have a reausable ajax method, what if we use a first class function as a callback? how would that be structured?

Comment: Never mind, i figured it out, I just pass it as part of the parameters `function makeAjaxRequest(requestType, url, data, onSuccess, onFail){ ...`

Answer (score 1):

Add this to ajax options:

```
dataType: "json",
```

and use

```
return Json(dataObject, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

in your action method.

Your

```
return result;
```

in the success handler of ajax is not a return for `check_product`. Pass another function (possibly anonymous) to `check_product` and call on ajax success.