# jquery ajax value assignment

Tags: jquery, jquery-callback

I have a strange situation with jquery ajax callback

```
var isOk = false;

 CheckStoreAvailability(store, function (result) {
            isOk = result;
             alert(result);  >> show message true    
});

alert(isOk );
```

it always show **false** no mater what return value in CheckStoreAvailability assigns to the isOk !!

i'm stucked now. Pls help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your `second` alert is executed `before` the `CheckStoreAvailability` is called due to asynchronous call. That is why you are not getting the updated value.

Check the answer in this [**post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648995/how-to-grab-return-value-from-an-ajax-call) how function call is used with `done()`, you may change your call accodingly.

Comment: Check the answer in this post how function call is used with done, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648995/how-to-grab-return-value-from-an-ajax-call, you may change your call accodingly

Answer (score 1):

AJAX is **asynchronous**, so that `alert(isOk);` line is going to be executed before the AJAX call has completed, and by extension before the value has been changed by the AJAX requests callback function.

If you want to work with that value, do it inside that function handling a response from the AJAX call.