# Passing Database Query Results to jQuery Sparkline Charts Using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, postgresql

I've created a `PIE` chart using `jquery-sparline`.

**Pie Chart :**

```
 $(".sparkline").sparkline([2,1], {
                type: 'pie',
                width: '100',
                height: '100',
                sliceColors: ['#F2441D','#fff'],
                borderWidth: 3,
                borderColor: '#F2441D'});
```

And I have a `PostgreSQL` database server.

Suppose I write this query `select "Group", COUNT(*) from test group by "Group"`.

My result will be something like this.

```
Label   Count
Group1  244
Group2  125
```

Now I need to replace these with value `2` and `1` in the javascript codes.

I'm using PHP over here.

Someone help me on how to do it.

Comment: do you want replace the value from 2 and 1 or do you want to sort the label column ?

Comment: I wanted to replace `2` and `1` with Group 1 and 2 value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure but i think you will have to print you value in html balise (hidden filed for exemple) and retrieve it using javascript : document.getElementById

exemple :

```
<input type="hidden" id="valueForJs" value="244-125">
<script>
   var obj = document.getElementById("valueForJs").value;
   var array = obj.split("-");

   alert('value = ' + array[0] + ' ' + array[1]);
   // now you have your 2 value and you can use it in your script below...
</script>
```

You can also put the value in a `span` and `hide` this span for exemple, but i think input will be cleaner.

Comment: I wanted to store that `244` and `125` to two javascript variables.

Comment: When you have it in an array it's easy to do for exemple : 
var value1 = array[0]; // 244
var value2 = array[1]; // 125
After you can use it as you want.
This is what you want ?

Comment: But I'm calling it through `ajax`. Through `ajax` I run this `function(result) {$('#msg').html(result)}` which returns the result of the `PostgreSQL` query result. Help me to assign returned value to a two javascript variables.

Comment: Look at this i think it's similar : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648995/how-to-grab-return-value-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: Sorry bro. That didn't help me. Shall I create a new post for a better understanding?

Comment: let's try one more time :p so you call a ajax script it return your reponse and you want to put that response into two js variables ?

Comment: Here's the [**link**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20857539/store-each-value-of-a-ajax-query-result-to-javascript-variables) for the post :)

Answer (score 0):

suppose we have result in $result array.
So, you can replace 2 with echo $result['Label']  and 1 with  echo $result['Count'] but in single inverted comma like below

'<?php echo $result['Label'] ?>'