# Unable to ECHO PostgreSQL Query Results - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, postgresql

I've successfully connected to a `PostgreSQL` database and even the `query` is running successfully.

But when I try to print the data using this code `echo $data` I get error as `Array to String Conversion`.

Tried searching in the `forum` and `google`. Nothing was fruitful.

Please help me.

Code used to convert it to array and print it.

```
if ( ! $myquery ) {
    echo pg_error();
    die;
}

$data = array();
for ($x = 0; $x < pg_num_rows($myquery); $x++) {
    $data[] = pg_fetch_assoc($myquery);
}
// echo json_encode($data);

// $data2 = array_shift($data);

echo $data;

pg_close($server);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the error :

```
Array to String Conversion
```

Try to display it using `var_dump` or `print_r` because it's an array.
The error says that you want to display an `array` with `echo` which can only display `string`.

exemple : `var_dump($data);`

Comment: `array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["Label"]=> string(3) "One" ["Count"]=> string(1) "1" } [1]=> array(2) { ["Status"]=> string(7) "Two" ["Count"]=> string(1) "3" } }` - I got a result like this. Can you please say me now how will I select pass this value to a `jquery` sparkline chart?

Comment: I need more information. To select a specific value you can do like this : $value = $data[0]['Label']; or $value = $data[1]['Status'];

Comment: Here's the [**link**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20852571/passing-database-query-results-to-jquery-sparkline-charts-using-php). I just wanted to how to pass that two numbers `1` and `3` into that jquery sparkline. I need to do like this? `<?php $value?>`

Comment: I'm not sure but i think you will have to print you value in html balise (hidden filed for exemple) and retrieve it using javascript : document.getElementById

Comment: can you mark this post as solved ? we will discuss in the other one.

Answer (score 1):

To just print the array (for debuging) use [var_dump()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) like this:

```
var_dump($data)
```

But if you want to echo every line in the array you have to loop:

```
foreach ($data as $row) {
    echo $row;
}
```

Comment: `array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["Label"]=> string(3) "One" ["Count"]=> string(1) "1" } [1]=> array(2) { ["Status"]=> string(7) "Two" ["Count"]=> string(1) "3" } }` - I got a result like this. Can you please say me now how will I select pass this value to a `jquery` sparkline chart?

Comment: The function `var_dump($data)` is only for debuging. Don't use this for actual coding... I don't know jQuery very well, but you could try to pass it to a JS variable like this `var data = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>` (This code hase to be in your JS block)

Answer (score 0):

You are pinting array with echo.Try `print_r();` that will print array. Like this `print_r($data);`

Answer (score 0):

Try using var_dump($var) or print_r($var) functions