# Store Each Value of a AJAX Query Result to Javascript Variables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Here's a jQuery-ajax function that returns some data from a php file.

```
$('.up').click(function() {
    var act = $('.active').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "database.php",
        data: {
            value: act
        }
    }).done(function(result) {
        $('#msg').html(result)
    });
});
```

I get the array result of the query. I have no problem with.

PHP Result :

```
array(2) {
  [0]=> array(2) { ["Label"]=> string(3) "Group1" ["Count"]=> string(1) "244" }
  [1]=> array(2) { ["Status"]=> string(7) "Group2" ["Count"]=> string(1) "125" }
}
```

Actual query result is this.

```
Label   Count
Group1  244
Group2  125
```

Now that I get the result. I wanted to store the numbers of the `Count` column to two different javascript variables.

So far I tried with this.

```
var value1 = "<?php echo htmlentities($data[0]['Count']) ?>";
var value2 = "<?php echo htmlentities($data[1]['Count']) ?>";
```

Tried replacing with the above piece of code with `result` in the ajax call.

But when I did this the click event itself was not triggered.

I've saved the numbers to two `php` variables namely `value1` and `value2`.

And in the result of the `ajax` call i get the result like `244125`.

Help me saving that number to two different `javascript` variables.

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look at my [**edits**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20857539/revisions) to your post. You might learn something from them (don't use backticks for non-code or emphasis, no need to use `<pre>`, there is no such thing called "jquery variable")

Comment: @ThiefMaster - Thanks for the edits and suggestions.

Comment: [`json_encode`](http://www.php.net/json_encode) is your friend.

Comment: @moonwave99 - I wanted to store the `ajax` result to `javascript` variables. Using `json_encode` how will it help me?

Comment: The php output should be formatted in a way javascript can easily read and understand. e.g JSON or XML.

Comment: @TastySpaceApple - I'm new to scripting. Any working code for my problem will be very much helpful for me get a better understanding on these things.

Comment: good info here http://us2.php.net/json_encode

Comment: I managed to do it. Here's the result `[{"Count":"244"},{"Count":"125"}]`. How can i make it to like this `[244, 125]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are going to do something with this data so you'll need to know what you are looking for.

Get your PHP to serve up JSON with keys like so:

```
{"Bob": "24", "Sue": "12"}
```

This way you can access the information you need or just loop through the whole lot. I've made a little fiddle which I am hoping will help you understand.

Ultimately you simply want to use the jQuery $.getJSON to pull the information and then deal with it however you please.

http://jsfiddle.net/PgVkL/

If you need PHP to output in the format you specified then you can do:

```
$people = array("24", "12", "16", "48");
var_dump(json_encode($people));
```

Here's the docs: https://www.php.net/json_encode

Comment: Happy New Year. And thank you very much for the reply. `{"Bob": "24", "Sue": "12"}` I can convert my sql query result to this json format. But what i actually i need it. I wanted to convert this json `{"Bob": "24", "Sue": "12"}` to this format `[24, 12]`. How will I do it?

Comment: Do you mean how to get the PHP to do this? Also if you do it this way you have no reference to what the data related to - it becomes data and not information?